# Fourier Transform and Trigonometry polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with period 1. Let $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}^c$, then $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f(n\theta) = \int_0^1 f(t) dt.$$

I think that this problem is connected to Fourier series (in Hilbert space).

Here is what I plan to do : I try to do when $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial ($f(t) = \sum_{k= -n}^n c_ke^{2\pi ikt }, c_k \in \mathbb{C}, n \geq 0)$ and use the follwoing lemma to approximate

Lemma 1 : $\mathscr{G} = \{\sum_{k= -n}^n c_ke^{2\pi ikt} : c_k \in \mathbb{C}, n\geq 0\}$ is dense in C($\mathscr{T}$) = $\{f | f \ \mbox{continuous with period 1} \}$, that is, for each $f$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there is $g_\epsilon \in \mathscr{G}$ $$ \ \max_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t) - g_\epsilon (t)| \leq \epsilon.$$

I try by plug in $f = ce^{2\pi i t}$, but it seems messing up, and no sign of why LHS and RHS equals.

Hint or suggestions please ?

๊Update : Let $f(t) = c_0$ complex constant. Then $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N c_0 = c_0 = \int_0^1 c_0 dx.$$
For $f(t) = c_0 + c_1 e^{2\pi i t} + c_{-1}e^{-2\pi i t}$, then
$$c_0 + (\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (c_1 e^{2\pi i n\theta } + c_{-1}e^{-2\pi i n\theta})) \ \mbox{and} \ \int_0^1 f(t) dt = c_0.$$
So I need to show that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (c_1 e^{2\pi i n\theta } + c_{-1}e^{-2\pi i n\theta}) = 0.$ Generally, for any trig. polys. $f$, I need $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (\sum_{k= -m, k \neq 0}^mc_k e^{2 \pi i k (n \theta)}) = 0.$$

Any suggestion in proving that limit ?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you put some context on the question. Where is this question from? e.g., what class/book/etc...?

Comment: Also, there must be a typo/missing information: $f(x)=x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f(n\theta)=n\theta$, and $\frac{1}{N}\sum n\theta=\frac{1}{N}\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\theta\rightarrow\infty$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: @charlestoncrabb Sorry, I miss that $f$ is of period 1. This is a question taken form past quals exams in real analysis. I try to do it, but seems hopeless.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb you might come up with more easy approach. All I say above is just what I try to do. It might turn out that this method is completely useless.